# How to reverse the order of a row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Is it possible to reverse order of a single row in a dataframe:

from:

```
   col1   col2   col3
0  65      34     1
1   1       2     3
2   1       2     3
```

to:

```
   col1   col2   col3
0   1      34     65
1   1       2     3
2   1       2     3
```

I have tried creating a new row with reversed values from row 0.

not sure why:

```
df.loc[3] = df.iloc[0][::-1]
```

does not work..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the `.values` at the end

```
df.iloc[0,:]=df.iloc[0,:][::-1].values
df
Out[783]: 
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    34    65
1     1     2     3
2     1     2     3
```

Comment: What is **,:** required?

Comment: @Joey this is my coding habit ... you can `df.loc[0] = df.iloc[0][::-1].values`, for the `,:` reminder me that is select from the row or column , when I doing a code validation , that is more easy for me and my co-worker recognizes that . :-)